# how to set height dynamically in table from dictionary in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In My TableView I am calculating my cell's height as per dynamic data,

Now here I want to do one thing,

I want to calculate table's height for only one time ,

after that I want to store it in a array so that when that row come again it should not calculate the whole size.

for this I want to declare a dictionary. In that I want to access two things . Height in integer and status for height is calculated or not.

Now status will note status is true or not. If height is calculated then status is true and height will be stored.

now when I come to there again . it will check if status is true then height should be fetch from dictionary only .

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `-heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method for that:

```
- (CGFloat)heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *dict = // get your dictionary for this indexPath

    if([[dict valueForKey:@"status"] boolValue] == YES) {
        return [[dict valueForKey:@"height"] floatValue];
    } else {
        return 44.0f;
    }
}
```

---

I wrote this code assumming that your dictionary is like:

```
status -> NSNumber: bool [YES/NO]
height -> NSNumber: float
```

---

You can make this dictionary in `-viewDidLoad` like:

```
NSNumber *status = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; // or NO
NSNumber *height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:60.0f]; // or 100.0f, for example
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:status,@"status",height,@"height"];
```

Then you can add this dictionary to some array and read it in `-heightForRow...`

Comment: Yes my dictionary is exactly like this. but where should I declare this? I mean where and how?? can u tell me?

Comment: and one more thing...while storing I want to set that .. for indexpath.row  1 the height is 50.0 .. where can I do this ?

Comment: k..got it kashiv.. thanks bro.. got it..let me do it now.. a million thanks .. :D

Comment: kashiv , one thing.. when declaring I have set the height 60.0 .. now I am doing some calculation .. I want that after calculation. the 60.0 should be replaced by my calculated ans. how to do this?

Comment: Do you store your values in NSArray?

Comment: No I am doing calculation in heightForRow... mathod.. I directly want to store values for height and status .. I want to set from there only?? how should I do this?

Comment: and in this line I am getting a warning `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:status,@"status",height,@"height"];
` and the warning is missing sentinel in function call

Comment: 1. You can do `float heightFloat; heightFloat = // your calculations` and then `NSNumber *height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatHeight];`. 2. I forgot to add `,nil` after `@"height"`. Add it and error will go away ;)